# Drawing only a portion of screen using glScissor in Android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

With Android OpenGL ES, more specifically with LibGDX library, I'm trying to redraw only a part of the screen (the rest of the screen was previously drawn and need not be redrawn) using the following code:

```
Gdx.gl20.glViewport(x, y, width, height);           
Gdx.gl20.glScissor(x, y, width/2, height/2);
Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);                
Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

_batch.begin();         
_batch.draw(_imgTimeBackground, 70, 215);
_batch.end();

Gdx.gl20.glDisable(GL20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
```

The screen should be:
[image: valid image]

But the region outside of the scissor region ends up being rendered as well, incorrectly:
[image: actual image]

In addition to `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`, I have tried clearing `GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT`, `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`, and all combinations of the 3 (including not calling `glClear`), but to no avail. Moving `glClear` to the very beginning draws the scissor region correctly but clears the region outside of the scissor, which defeats the purpose of the scissor.

Let me know how I can draw only a portion of a screen in OpenGL without clearing/redrawing the rest of the screen.

Comment: `glClear` should work with `glScissor` correctly: https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/134533-glClear-with-glScissor

Comment: Please update your example code to indicate where any batch begin/end calls are (if you're using `SpriteBatch` or other Libgdx infrastructure).

Comment: @P.T. I just updated the code. I saw the specification - maybe I'm not using it correctly. I also tried using ScissorStack, a LibGDX wrapper around glScissor, but it has the same problem.

Comment: What do you mean with "redraw only a part of the screen"? I assume that you are rendering the entire screen each frame? Only rendering a portion and assuming that the rest will remain in tact from the previous render call wont work. Also make sure that glClear is the first call you make after the back buffer is bound (the first call in the render method).

Comment: I think @Xoppa is on to something: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7320/how-to-do-partial-updates-in-opengl